# Prove for the following set of Diophantine equations.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Prove that there are no integers $q$, $m$, $n$ and $p$ for the following Diophantine equations:-

1. $$      7m^2 = 1 + q^2$$
2. $$p^2 - 1 = 7n^2$$

Comment: $1+q^2 = 7m^2 = q^2-1 \implies 1=-1$

Comment: what? please explain what did you do

Comment: you have $7m^2$ in both equations

Comment: I think there is a confusion regarding the question. I have edited it. Please revisit the edited question.

Comment: My apologies. For the first equation, look mod 7 - $-1$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get the part of the $(mod7)$ and $-1$ not being a perfect square. Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: $0^2 = 0, 1^2 = 1, 2^2 = 4, 3^3 = 2, 4^2 = 2, 5^2 = 4, 6^2 = 1$ in mod $7$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50202/discussion-between-lucifer-and-mathworker21).

Comment: The second one HAS solutions: $1^2-1=7\cdot0^2$,    $8^2-1=7\cdot3^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$  $7m^2=q^2+1$

Write $q=7a+r, r \in [0, 6]$. Then, $7$ is to divide into $r^2+1$. But none of $1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37$ is divisible by $7$.

$(2) 7n^2=p^2-1$

This statement is wrong because $p=8$ and $n=3$ satisfy the Diophantine equation.

Comment: Nice, would you mind putting this mathjax/latex?

Comment: I am new to this site. I do not know how to do it.